# How to construct a Pushdown Automata for a given laguage

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automaton

How to construct the pushdown automata for the following language
L = {a^n b^m a^2m | m, n belong to N}.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck with your attempt? As a starting point, do you know how to define a PDA for the language `b^m a^m`? How can you extend that PDA into one that matches `b^m a^2m`? And then how could you add `a^n` to the start of that PDA?

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about pushdown automaton(PDA), there are two typed of PDA: dpda and npda. 
Now let's just have a look at the question it says, a^n b^m a^2m where n,m >=1.

Now the term a^n will not have any effect on b^ma^2m because n and m are not dependent on each other. So this question just break down to PDA of b^m a^2m because only this term will need a stack so that we can balance every 'b' with 2 'a'. Now since the points of transitions are clear, therefore this is DPDA.

PDA for the given problem will look like:
[image]

Where 'z'  is initial stack symbol and '^' is null and  x,y/z means when input symbol is x and top of stack is y then replace top of stack with z. Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have  the number of a‟s surrounding the b‟s have the same number of occurences followed by independent of number of a‟s.

Assuming m=3,n=2

The sample string will be aabbaaa

For a Push Down Automata, the final state is reached when the stack is empty once the whole string has been processed, and hence we need some kind of symmetry in the language to be processed to ensure corresponding pop operations occur for every push operation

So, to construct a PDA in this example, it would be better that „b; be treated as a kind of delimiter rather than an element to be pushed onto the stack i.e. whenever we encounter „b‟, we shall not perform any specific, thus treating „b‟ as a mere separator between the starting and ending two an

Claim:

Once we encounter the first an sequence, we push „a‟ elements into the stack. Then, when we encounter „b‟, we shall not perform any operation. And after the sequence of „b‟ is over and we encounter the trailing an , we shall pop the elements out.

At the end of the string processing activity, we find that „b‟ was used merely as a separator between the first and last an sequence and by using „b‟ that way, the stack is empty eventually.

Stack operations:

δ(S,a,z0)=(S,az0) (az0 pushed into stack)

δ(S,a,a)=(S,aa) (aa pushed into stack)

δ(A,b,a)=(A) (no operation)

δ(A,a,az0)=(A, є) (a is popped from the stack)

δ(A, є,z0)=(Q, z0) (Stack empty condition)